# How do I separate tabs in the Taskbar

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, taskbar

I want to separately move the tabs (of the same application) in the taskbar.

I have 2 Chrome Windows open. If I want to move either of them to another position inside the taskbar, both are moved, as if they are glued together.

How do I move them separately?

Answer (score 1):

Try [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](https://ramensoftware.com/7-taskbar-tweaker)'s `Taskbar Inspector` feature

1. Install 7+ Taskbar Tweaker (portable installation is also possible)
2. Move the tabs to a separate window
3. Open taskbar inspector
4. Select the window with your preferred tabs, right click & `Change Application ID` to `random group`

You can now move the 2 Chrome/Firefox windows separately on the taskbar

Screenshot:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKZV2.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a built-in feature of Windows. Typically, browsers implement their own Tab handling.

In Firefox, you can

- right click a tab
- select "Move to own window"

which will result in two separate windows that can be moved independently.

This is e.g. not available in Internet Explorer. There you have to

- select and hold the tab
- drag it outside of Internet Explorer

or

- select File/New window (Ctrl+N)
- type the URL again

Perhaps you also want to make sure you set the taskbar properties to "never combine":

[image: Taskbar properties]

However, you cannot move e.g. a Notepad++ tab between two command prompts. It'll always move it behind the two:

[image]

Comment: unfortunately it does not work. i cannot move them independently. i also noticed, that i cant move the folder-tabs of windows independently, too

Comment: @InsOp: oh, so you're dragging the items on the taskbar itself? I don't think that's possible, even not with 3rd party taskbar extensions like UltraMon, which I use.

Comment: @InsOp: I have attached a screenshot of the situation you probably have.

Comment: Thomas, yes that is the problem im experiencing! what a pity, it really disturbs my workflow

Answer (score 0):

You can separate tabs into different windows in Chrome. For that:

1. Select the tab you want to "detach" from the window
2. Press and hold the `ctrl` key
3. Drag and drop the tab to bottom.

Works also with Firefox.

Comment: thanks, but i was talking about the windows-taskbar, not the browser-taskbar

Comment: Do you mean this: http://i.imgur.com/QhC0dwP.png ?

Comment: No, look at Thomas post, thats what I ment

Comment: Yeah I thought of something like that. Not aware actually if this is doable at all.